# Как  правильно перерисовать JTable при изменении данных в модели?

Tags: java, swing

Я создал свой класс модели данных, унаследовав `AbstractTableModel`. Он хранит в себе ссылку на `ArrayList` с сущностями. 
Вот примитивный пример:

```
package jtable_example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel{
    ArrayList<Human> humans;
    MyTableModel(ArrayList<Human> humans) {
        super();
        this.humans = humans;
    }
    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return humans.size();
    }
    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 3;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int r, int c) {
        switch (c) {   
            case 0:
                return humans.get(c).getName();
            case 1:
                return humans.get(c).getSurname();
            case 2:
                return humans.get(c).getTelephone();
            default:
                return "";
        }        
    }
    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int c) {
        switch (c) {
            case 0:
                return "Name";
            case 1:
                return "Surname";
            case 2:
                return "Telephone";
            default:
                return "Unknow";
        }
    }
}
```

Если я добавлю в `ArrayList` значение, в таблице оно не меняется. Как мне обновить `JTable` при обновлении `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел вариант. После добавления данных в `ArrayList`, нужно вызвать у объекта класса `JTable` метод `updateUI()`.

Кстати, можно еще выполнить обновление, вызвав у модели таблицы метод fireDataChanged(). Я его засунул в слушатель и теперь все окей.

Comment: Если смотреть с высоты высокой материи, то это неправильное решение. По идее, у модели таблицы есть листенеры.. их и надо уведомлять об изменениях в таблице и она сама решит, что надо перерисовать и надо ли вообще.

Comment: updateUI() - применять для обновления таблицы, например, после смены сортировки

Comment: сортировка - это одно, а обновление сами данных - другое. Таблица может не перерисовывать вообще ничего, если данные изменяются в ячейках, которые не видны или перерисовать только нужные ячейки вместо того, чтобы рисовать всё что видимо.

Comment: я к тому, что если в бд появились новые записи, то updateUI() не добавит их в таблицу =)

Comment: Ну так из БД они вытаскиваются в массив. Про который "знает" модель таблицы. Как сообщить самой таблице, что бы при изменении массива обновился UI?